# Meaning of "get it on"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does phrase "get it on" mean in sentence "Am I wrong, cause I wanna get it on, till I die". I found a translation where "get it on" is translated as "to have sex" but i think it is not appropriate translation for this here.

Comment: That is exactly what it means.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So chorus of Unchained song from Django, means 
"Am i wrong, cause i wanna have sex, till I die"?
I don't get it :)

Comment: Yes. It literally means "*Is it wrong that all I want to do is fuck until I die?*". That is what it means.

Comment: Wow, that's a terrible song.  At least, listen to the [Marvin Gaye song](http://www.youtube.com/v/BKPoHgKcqag).

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly what it means and reinforced by the another part of the song:

```
Only wish to breed
I explode into a million seeds
Ya’ll remember me
Legendary live eternally
```

Answer (score -2):

You all may be right... but it seems "get it on" here could mean "ride or die"... like the event ("it") is riding (for revenge) rather than sex. Seems more thug and less petty, but tupac was sometimes shallow in his lyricism.